# Update Variable Value from a Private Internal Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to update the value of `someObject.config.title` to the value that is set from the `click` event. How do I go about doing this?

Also have a seperate question, is there any way to set `$this` as a global var that can accessed through any of the child functions of this object?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uw07dovp/)

```
var someObject = {
    config: {
        title: ''
    },
    init: function() {
        // Any way to set $this as a global var that can accessed through any of the child functions of this object?
        var $this = this,
            title = $this.config.title;

        $('button').on( 'click' , function() {
            title = 'yo, waz gud son!';  
            // This reference works
            //$this.referenceTitle( title ); 
        });
         // This reference is undefined, need to update original value
        $this.referenceTitle( title ); 
    },
    referenceTitle: function(arg) {
        console.log( arg );
    }
}

someObject.init();
```

Comment: tried, didn't work. even after button click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `someObject.config` is not private.

To make it a private variable (and get a reference to `$this`) you can do:

```
var someObject = (function () {
    var config = {
        title: ''
    }; // config is now a private variable

    var $this = {
        init: function() {
            var title = config.title;

            $('button').on( 'click' , function() {
                title = 'yo, waz gud son!';  
                // This reference works
                //$this.referenceTitle( title ); 
            });
             // This reference is undefined, need to update original value
            $this.referenceTitle( title ); 
        },
        referenceTitle: function(arg) {
            console.log( arg );
        }
    };
    return $this;
}()); // <-- immediate invocation

someObject.init();
```